# SMS Retriever API not calling SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION from Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION is not been called. I am using Firebase Phone Auth:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                mPhoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                activity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
```

and I am trying to retrieve SMS using the [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)

```
SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(activity);

// Starts SmsRetriever, which waits for ONE matching SMS message until timeout
// (5 minutes). The matching SMS message will be sent via a Broadcast Intent with
// action SmsRetriever#SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.

Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();

task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
```

I am registering BroadcastReceiver onResume and unregistering it on Pause:

```
public class MySMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

        switch(status.getStatusCode()) {
            case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // Get SMS message contents
                String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);

                break;
            case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:

                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Could be Firebase SMS format? Could be not compatible with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, because Firebase Auth SMS format is not editable and SMS retriever API need a specific format. Fortunately, Firebase Auth SDK uses internally a similar way to identify SMS code so in Android phones usually it takes it automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I tried on my friends new Huawei and it didn't seem to work, though I didn't have it plugged into my laptop to see any logging.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the dependency to:
`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0"`
Register your **broadcast receiver** in **AndroidMaifest.xml**:

```
<receiver android:name=".MySMSBroadcastReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

thats it!!.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with all the implemented dependencies and also check their external libraries code as well. if not your broadcast receiver then surely it might be some external libraries which are affecting your application.

In my case it was actually the broadcast receiver which was not registered in manifest, but before that i've tried around 50 times to submit my app, and it got rejected every single time, so first check your code whether is there any mistake in your code or any problem related to your libraries. and meanwhile try once to publish your application without this sms retrieving functionality.

How I've checked my mistake by removing suspicious code one by one and publishing app. and at the end when I removed my sms retrieval code then my app directly got accepted, then I rewrote my sms retrieval code with proper documentation provided by google and it was working.

you can follow my answer as well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66684609/14280161

Answer (score -1):

Use below dependency and try again

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.4'