# SMS Retriever API not working with Firebase PhoneAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

I developed one android application that has firebase phone number authentication.
After enter phone number, firbase sent Verification OTP number via SMS.
So I add and allow SMS Read permission in my application

Now as per Google Play Policy, We need to remove SMS Read permission and implement SMS Retriever API.

So I implement SMS Retriever API with `SmsRetrieverClient`, `SMSBroadcastReceiver` with necessary dependency.

I register broadcast receiver, submit phone number to firebase.
I started `client.startSmsRetriever();` and It successfully started with `onSuccess()` callback.

And also I received SMS from Firebase but `SMSBroadcastReceiver` not getting any callback regarding `CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS` and after 5 minutes I getting callback regarding `CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT`.

So any issue regarding firebase message format or other else?

So please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: found any solutin?

Comment: I'm interested in this also

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran You found any solution to this. I am getting the same ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth please refer this document in this onVerificationCompleted callback will be called if user using same number in that device

Comment: Please share some code as the information you have stated above were seem to be correct. Please check whether app was registered in **AndroidManifest.xml**. Please see[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670263/sms-retriever-api-not-calling-sms-retrieved-action-from-firebase-phone-auth/54087058#54087058)

Comment: @shizhen how did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Almost an answer :
It can't work because the "format" of the SMS content for SMS Retriever to work is "#".... and SHA256 from the app but Firebase SMS format is different so the SMS Retriever is not "recognising" the SMS as a valid one.

Comment: Is it possible now?