# Got a mail from google saying "Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection". What can I do?

Tags: android, android-studio

The below are the dependencies that i used. is there any vulnerability with my dependencies...I have followed the guide that they provide, still it is rejected

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    ADDITIONAL LIBRARIES
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.1'

    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
    //implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:3.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.3'
    implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0' }
```

The below is showing all of [help-center](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555) suggested, i have add "android:exported="false" " my manifest file, but the app is still rejected. I have lots of activities. And I got lots of "startActivity()", I also open GoogleMap and YouTube from the app, could that cause a problem?
I am also using "**startActivityForResult()**"  which is already depreciated, could the cause the problem too?

> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     package="com.give.android_fisheries_2">
>     <!--
>          The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
>          Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
>          location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
>     -->
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
>
>     <uses-feature
>         android:name="android.hardware.camera"
>         android:required="true"
>         />
>
>     <supports-screens
>         android:anyDensity="true"
>         android:largeScreens="true"
>         android:normalScreens="true"
>         android:smallScreens="true"
>         android:xlargeScreens="true" />
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>         android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon_update_larger"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:largeHeap="true"
>         android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_update_larger_round"
>         android:supportsRtl="true"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>
>         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
>
>         <activity android:name=".tutorial.TutorialMenuActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer"
>             android:exported="false"/>
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".registration.EditUserActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".fisherman.FishermanIdActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".admin.AdminHomeActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
>
>         <uses-library
>             android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
>             android:required="false" />
>
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".farmer.FarmerPondListActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".farmer.FarmerHomeActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".registration.OtpPhoneNumberActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".registration.OtpPageActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>       
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".tutorial.YouTubeTutorialActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".fisherman.FishermanMainActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".fisherman.FishermanFormActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".river.RiverMenuActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".river.RiverListActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
>             android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
>
>        
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".admin.SmsActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".admin.FishPondMapActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".admin.FarmerListActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".farmer.FarmerUploadDataActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".farmer.GetLocationInMapActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".farmer.FarmerCenterActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".registration.LoginActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".registration.RegistrationActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
>             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
>         <activity
>             android:exported="true"
>
>             android:name=".SplashScreen"
>             android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>         <activity
>             android:exported="false"
>
>             android:name=".MainActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>             android:theme="@style/AppThemeFarmer" />
>
>
> <receiver android:name=".otpReader.SmsBroadcastReceiver"
>     android:exported="false"
>     android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.permission.SEND">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
>
>         </intent-filter>
> </receiver>
>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

**The SmsBroadcastReceiver used is below**...

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public SmsBroadcastReceiverListener smsBroadcastReceiverListener;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Status smsRetrieverStatus = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

        switch (smsRetrieverStatus.getStatusCode()) {
            case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                Intent messageIntent = extras.getParcelable(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT);
                smsBroadcastReceiverListener.onSuccess(messageIntent);
                break;
            case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                smsBroadcastReceiverListener.onFailure();
                break;
        }
    }
}
public interface SmsBroadcastReceiverListener {
    void onSuccess(Intent intent);
    void onFailure();
}
```

}

SMS is read automatically like this...

```
      private void startSmsUserConsent() {
    SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this);

    client.startSmsUserConsent(null).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Waiting for OTP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP auto-read error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    smsBroadcastReceiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
    smsBroadcastReceiver.smsBroadcastReceiverListener =
            new SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsBroadcastReceiverListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_USER_CONSENT);

                    otpButtonPage.setEnabled(true);
                    otpButtonPage.setText("Next");

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                }
            };
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerBroadcastReceiver();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_USER_CONSENT) {
        if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data != null)) {
            //That gives all message to us.
            // We need to get the code from inside with regex
            //IF ALLOW IS CLICK
            String message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);


            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           /* textViewMessage.setText(
                    String.format("%s - %s", getString(R.string.received_message), message));
            */
            getOtpFromMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show AndoidManifest.

Comment: it's not about dependencies, I think it's about intent transitions, if you used an implicit intents that any application can accept and use, or if you used a broadcast with a broadcast receiver, check this link and read the warning at the end of the section, see if it helps - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Types

Comment: @CoolMind thanks for the reply , i have post my Android Manifest

Comment: @Thanpuia, thanks. Do you have BroadcastReceivers in code? Also maybe AndrodManifests of dependencies may lead to this error.

Comment: @CoolMind , yes i used SmsBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @CoolMind I am using this "startActivityForResult()" which is depreciated for taking pictures from the gallery. could this create the problem?

Comment: @Thanpuia, I didn't get this error and don't know. But your code is correct. `startActivityForResult()` for taking pictures cannot be a reason. Do you ask permissions for SMS? Maybe there should be a BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670263/sms-retriever-api-not-calling-sms-retrieved-action-from-firebase-phone-auth. How do you read SMS?

Comment: @CoolMind, thanks for the suggestion. I have added BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest like [stackoverflow.com/questions/45670263](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670263/sms-retriever-api-not-calling-sms-retrieved-action-from-firebase-phone-auth). I published to playstore again and still got rejected. Is there anything that you could suggest again?

Comment: @CoolMind i have edited the question and put some code on "How I read the SMS". I would be very grateful if you could give suggestions again

Comment: @CoolMind , I enquire with the Google Play Team and says that...
"I see that you have submitted your app again for review. However, I’ve found that your app (App Bundle Version: 8) still violates the Device and Network Abuse policy, which contains an Intent Redirection issue which can allow malicious apps to access private app components or files.

    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity->startActivityForResult"

Could this be helpful?

Comment: @Thanpuia, thanks! Please, read https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555. Maybe there would be interesting points. Also maybe should switch to SMS Retriever Auth?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it. Thank you a million times for all of your answers. Its was the broadcast receiver, with the help of this [article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request#2_start_listening_for_incoming_messages) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682241/register-a-broadcast-receiver-from-a-service-in-a-new-thread/10682678#10682678) i was able to make some changes and the google play finally accept my update. Below is the new code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_page);

    /* //TO COMPLY WITH GOOGLE PLAY POLICY*/
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyNewThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    handler = new Handler(looper);       
  ....
  }

 private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    smsBroadcastReceiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
    smsBroadcastReceiver.smsBroadcastReceiverListener =
            new SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsBroadcastReceiverListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_USER_CONSENT);

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                }
            };
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION);

  /*TO COMPLY WITH GOOGLE PLAY POLICY*/
    registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter, SmsRetriever.SEND_PERMISSION,handler);
}
```